# How can obtain it?

Tags: gams-math

I have  a set j and parameter edge. I have a graph too.

```
    Set j/1*5/;
   Alias(j,jp);

   Parameter edge(j,jp)
```

That edge(j,jp) =1  if there is arc  from j to jp  , and it's 0 if there isn't arc from j to jp. 
 I maked edge(j,jp) .

I want to define a set or parameter , for saving index of neighborhood of node "j".

I Mean  , neighborhood (j)={jp  : edge(j,jp)=1}

I write ,below command but I get error.

```
  Set  neighborhood (j)
  Neighborhood (j)$edge (j,jp) =JP.val;
```

How can I obtain neighborhood of especial node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you work with an directed graph and assume there is just one neighbor for each j? Then, try this:

```
Set j/1*3/;
Alias(j,jp);

Parameter edge(j,jp) / 1.2 1, 2.3 1, 3.1 1 /;

Parameter Neighborhood (j);
Neighborhood (j) = sum(jp$edge(j,jp), jp.val);
```

Otherwise: What do you expect to see in Neighborhood, if there is more than one neighbor?

Comment: hello ,have a great day :-)  . I want to have a set of all neighborhood of node j . for example if we have edge (1.2 ,1.3,1.6,1.10) in graph . then neighborhood ('1')={2,3,6,10} .

Comment: I can't  give this set  neighborhood (j)={jp : edge(j,jp)=1} , I try to  use loop ،  but again I don't have all neighborhood.

Comment: Like this?

Set j/1*3/;
Alias(j,jp);

Parameter edge(j,jp) / 1.2 1, 2.3 1, 3.1 1 /;

Parameter Neighborhood (j,jp);
Neighborhood (j,jp)$edge(j,jp) = jp.val;

Comment: thanks ,it's right ,but I want to have one index only . I write , Loop(j,  neighborhood (j)$edge(j,jp)=jp.val. ); but in this situation ,I have errors in set jp . is it possible I have one index 'j' only ?

Comment: How do you want to store multiple values in one index? Neighborhood(j) can have exactly one value for each j, not more.